# Buildfire: access userData from plugin tester

Tags: buildfire

I am developing a plugin with the Buildfire-sdk. 
I have been using the pluginTester on my local machine.
I want to be able to store and retrieve data for each user.
But there is no user logged in with the pluginTester,
and so I get "no logged in user found" as an error.

Is there a way to simulate logged in users on the pluginTester?

```
function getUserData(){
        buildfire.userData.get('main record',function(err,data){
            if(err)
                console.log('there was a problem retrieving your data');
            else
                console.log('got your data ' + JSON.stringify(data) );
        });

    }
```

I expected user Data.
I got:

```
no logged in user found
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a login button on the top right corner of the control side of the plugin.
[image]